# if the option is already added, then the next time i add the option that already exist will not display in the add modal option

Tags: php, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP46o.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHe8c.png)

## i add the position 'captain' then when i add again the option captain will be disabled or did not show in he option because its already existing

```
<!-- ========================= MODAL ======================= -->
            <div id="addCourseModal" class="modal fade">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Manage officials</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">

                                     <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Positions:</label> <span style="color:red;">*</span>
                                    <select name="ddl_pos" required="" class="form-control input-sm">
                                        <option selected="" disabled="">-- Select Position -- </option>
                                        <option value="Captain">Barangay Captain</option>
                                        <option value="Kagawad(Ordinance)">Barangay Kagawad(Ordinance)</option>
                                        <option value="Kagawad(Public Safety)">Barangay Kagawad(Public Safety)</option>
                                        <option value="Kagawad(Tourism)">Barangay Kagawad(Tourism)</option>
                                        <option value="Kagawad(Budget & Finance)">Barangay Kagawad(Budget & Finance)</option>
                                        <option value="Kagawad(Agriculture)">Barangay Kagawad(Agriculture)</option>
                                        <option value="Kagawad(Education)">Barangay Kagawad(Education)</option>
                                        <option value="Kagawad(Infrastracture)">Barangay Kagawad(Infrastracture)</option>
                                        <option value="SK Chairman">SK Chairman</option>
                                        <option value="Secretary">Barangay Secretary</option>
                                        <option value="Treasurer">Barangay Treasurer</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

Comment: can you please add more server side ( php ) code to understand the issue.

Comment: me i ask your email sir?

Comment: sorry, but in stack overflow this is public post and we can't share our email id.
Hope you can understand.